# MYSQL query equivalent in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have a django project with 2 models called wca and identifiers, I am wanting to update a field called 'secid' within identifiers model pulled from the equivalent field in wca model where code from identifiers model matches isin field in wca model.

**Models**

```
class Identifier(TimeStampMixin, models.Model):
    secid = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
    code_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=12, db_index=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
        
        
class Wca(models.Model):
    secid = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, db_index=True)
    isin = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, db_index=True)
    uscode = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, db_index=True)
    sedol = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, db_index=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.secid)
```

I have the working sql code for this but would like to convert into django equivalent for best practice. My sql query is as follows:

```
    UPDATE portfolio_identifier
    left outer join product_wca on portfolio_identifier.code = product_wca.isin
    SET
    portfolio_identifier.SecID = product_wca.secid
    WHERE
    code_type = 'ISIN';
```

**Edit**

The following is the updated MYSQL query to handle mismatches (NULL values):

```
UPDATE portfolio_identifier
inner join product_wca on portfolio_identifier.code = product_wca.isin and portfolio_identifier.code_type = 'ISIN'
SET portfolio_identifier.SecID = product_wca.secid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, F, When, Case, Value, IntegerField

Identifier.objects.filter(
    code_type='ISIN'
    code__in=Wca.objects.values('isin')
).update(
    secid=Subquery(
        Wca.objects.filter(
            isin=OuterRef('code')
        ).annotate(
            secid_new=Case(
                When(
                    secid__isnull=False,
                    then=F('secid')
                ),
                default=Value(0),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
       ).values('secid_new').distinct()
    )
)
```

Or if the case when the WCA secid is not needed then:

```
Identifier.objects.filter(
    code_type='ISIN'
    code__in=Wca.objects.values('isin')
).update(
    secid=Subquery(
        Wca.objects.filter(
            isin=OuterRef('code')
        ).values('secid')
    )
)
```

Comment: @rob this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the new query, I only just had a chance to try out now. Unfortunately I'm receiving the following error:

raise IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args))
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'secid' cannot be null")

Comment: @rob can you check if for the row that you are getting this error, exists an WCA record with the isin field = to the code field in the Identifier model? I think that for one row the filter in the subquery in empty and that's why this error is raised

Comment: Hi yes I can confirm there are and will generally be ISINs in identifier model that do not exist in WCA, I knew this previously having had the same issue on the first answer you kindly gave. Sorry If I was not clear enough, I adapted my original sql query to be an inner join and also added code_type = 'ISIN' on the join rather than having where clause which resolves the Null issue - this is what I'm after in django equivalent. I will add my working mysql query to my question for your reference. Thanks

Comment: @rob i updated my answer to fit that, my suggestion is to use an aditional filter in the Identifier so select only the ones their code can be found in the Wca. this avoid the Null. An alternative could be using`extra` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra but i preffer this solution.

Answer (score 2):

This should work with some changes in the model and fields names.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Identifier.objects.filter(code_type='ISIN').update(
    secid=Subquery(
        Wca.objects.filter(
            isin=OuterRef('code')
        ).values('secid')
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm getting isssues running this, my query slightly changed now as in I no longer need the case statement so original query looks like this now:

`UPDATE portfolio_identifier
 left outer join product_wca on portfolio_identifier.code = product_wca.isin
 SET
 portfolio_identifier.SecID = product_wca.secid
 WHERE
 code_type = 'ISIN';
`

Comment: Then you should replace the statement to something like `Identifiers.objects.filter(code_type = 'ISIN').update(SecID=Subquery(WCA.objects.filter(code=OuteRef('isin')).values('secid')))`

Comment: To give you a better response please share your Models.

Comment: I have updated my question with the models and updated query. I am basically wanting to run the equivalent django query to run in a view. much appreciated

Comment: @rob I have updated my answer to fit your Models.

Comment: This works perfectly - I had a minor issue where I had duplicate isins in Wca but figured out to distinct it as follows:

changing: `.values('secid')` to this: `.values('secid').distinct()`

Thank you so much for your help with this!

Comment: Really sorry, I just realised I now need my original case statement where null mark as 0  or to adapt this to be inner join instead of outer join?